# Removing a substring from a string in C

Tags: c, string, loops

I already have the code that removes a substring from a string (word) in C, but I don't understand it. Can someone explain it to me? It doesn't use functions from the standard library. I tried to analyze it myself, but certain parts I still don't understand - I put them in the comments. I just need to figure out how does this all work.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void remove(char *s1, char *s2);

int main()
{
   char s1[101], s2[101];
   printf("First word: ");
   scanf("%s", s1);
   printf("Second word: ");
   scanf("%s", s2);
   remove(s1, s2);
   printf("The first word after removing is '%s'.", s1);

   return 0;
}
void remove(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   int i = 0, j, k;
   while (s1[i])       // ITERATES THROUGH THE FIRST STRING s1?
   {
       for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);   // WHAT DOES THIS LINE DO?
          if (!s2[j])           // IF WE'RE AT THE END OF STRING s2? 
             {
                 for (k = i; s1[k + j]; k++)   //WHAT DOES THIS ENTIRE BLOCK DO?
                    s1[k] = s1[k + j];
                    s1[k] = 0;
              }
          else
              i++;    // ???
    }
}
```

Comment: the for loop with `j` check if  the word `s2` is into `s1` at position `i`. if the word is found the for loop with `k` shift all the letter till the end of `s1` to remove `s2`. This function will remove all word `s2` into `s1`

Comment: Whenever you are faced with a bit of pointer code you do not understand, take out a piece of paper and a pencil, write the contents of the array or string out on the paper and then write `0123456...` out under each character. Put a mark at the index currently pointed to by the pointer (usually the beginning), and then work through the code, moving the mark each time the pointer changes until you are comfortable with what is being done. No magic.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @DavidC.Rankin, this is the kind of algorithm that more words won't necessarily help explain if you don't get it immediately. Someone kind enough might draw some diagrams or animations and post them here, but I wouldn't count on it (thus why taking out a piece of paper or a diagram tool you're proficient with and do it yourself is likely your best bet).

Comment: ... and stepping through it with a debugger, using a short sample string and a watch on each of these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `while (s1[i])` iterates through s1. Yes, you are right.

```
for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);
```

The above for loop checks whether the substring s2 is present in s1 starting from s1[i]. If it matches, s2 is completely iterated. If not, at the end of the for loop, s2[j] will not be null character. Example: if s1 = ITERATE and s2 = RAT, then the loop will execute completely only when i=3. 
so the `if (!s2[j])` holds then it means we have found a substring and i is the starting point of the substring in s1.

```
         for (k = i; s1[k + j]; k++)   //WHAT DOES THIS ENTIRE BLOCK DO?
            s1[k] = s1[k + j];
            s1[k] = 0;
```

The abov block removes the substring. So, for the ITERATE and RAT example, this is done by copying E and null char at positions where R and A were present. The for loop achieves this. If s2[j] is not null after for loop, the i is incremented to check for substribng from the next position of s1.

Answer (score 2):

Here main working of function is like :

-Skip the common part between both strings and assign the first string with new string.

```
while (s1[i])       // Yes It ITERATES THROUGH THE FIRST STRING s1
       {
           for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);   // Here it skips the part which is 
//similar in both
```

As this loop just increasing the index of common part so this will skip storing of data in s1.

```
if (!s2[j])           // IF WE'RE AT THE END OF STRING s2
{
 for (k = i; s1[k + j]; k++)   //Here it is re assigning the non common part.
 s1[k] = s1[k + j];
 s1[k] = 0;
}
else
 i++;    // it is req. if both have more values.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach of the functionality condensed in the comments

```
void remove(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   int i = 0, j, k;
   while (s1[i])       // Iterates through s1 (until it finds a zero)
   {
       for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);   // Iterates through s2 while both it is NOT the end of the string s2 and each character of s2 coincides with s1 (if s2 == s1, j points to the end of s2 => zero)
          if (!s2[j])           // If j point to the end of s2 => We've found the coincidence
             {
                 for (k = i; s1[k + j]; k++)   //Remove the coincident substring
                    s1[k] = s1[k + j];
                    s1[k] = 0;
              }
          else
              i++;    // There is no coincidence so we continue to the next character of s1
    }
}
```

Note: I also hace noticed that this may be easily exploted since it iterates out of s1 range.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down. You have

```
while (s1[i])
{
    // Code
}
```

This iterates through `s1`. Once you get to the end of the string, you have `\0`, which is the null terminator. When evaluated in a condition, it will evaluate to `0`. It may have been better to use a `for` here.

You then have

```
for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);
```

This does nothing but increment `j`. It should be noted that this expression does not have braces and it terminated with a semicolon, so the code after it shouldn't be executed within the loop body. If it did have the braces correctly, it would loop over the following `if/else` while `s2` was not null and `s2[j] == s1[i+j]`. I don't really have an explanation for the second part other than the character in `s2` is offset by an amount `i` in `s1`. This part could likely be improved to remove unnecessary iterations.

Then there's

```
if (!s2[j])
{
}
else
{
}
```

This checks to make sure the position in `s2` is valid and executes the removal of the string if so and otherwise increments `i`. It could be improved by returning in the `else` when `s2` could no longer fit in the remainder of `s1`.

```
for (k = i; s1[k + j]; k++)
    s1[k] = s1[k + j];
    s1[k] = 0;
```

This is another somewhat strange loop since due to the absence of braces, `s1[k] = 0` will be set outside of the loop. What happens here is that the string is compacted down by removing `s2` and shifting the character at `k+j` down to `k`. At the end of the loop `s1[k] = 0` ends the string in a null terminator to be properly ended.

If you want a deeper understanding, it may be worth trying to write your own code to do the same thing and then comparing afterwards. I have found that that generally helps more than reading a bunch of tests.